# Calling Functions repeatedly in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-expressions

I have the follwoing python code that I would like to convert to Mathematica. But I totally get stuck on how to deifne the functions I *def shouldSwap* and *def findPermutations* in Mathematica and then **call on *findPermutations* for index + 1**. How do I define such functions in Mathematica? Thank you very much for your help!

My python code:

```
def shouldSwap(string, start, curr):
for j in range(strat, curr):
    if string[j] == string[curr]:
         return 0
return 1

def findPermutations(string, index, n):
    if index >= n:
       print(''.join(String))
       return
    for i in range(index, n):
        check = shouldSwap(string index, i)
        if check:
            string[index], string[i] = string[i], string[index]
            findPermutations(string, index + 1, n)
            string[index], string[i] = string[i], string[index]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    string = list("ABCA")
    n = len(string)
    findPermutations(string, 0, n)
```

My hopelessly failed attempt to convert it to Mathematica:

```
string = List[A, B, C, A]
n = Length[string]
index = 0;
If[index>=n, string, Return]
If[index<n,
    For[i = index, i<n, i+1, 
            If[ 
                For[j = index, j<i, j++,
                           If[string[j] == string[i], Return,
                                   Swap[string[index], string[i]] and
             How do I do this???   findPermutations(string, index + 1, n) and
                                   Swap[string[index], string[i]]
                   ]
                 ]
          ]
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax errors in the Python code. Is there a reason for wanting to transliterate it? The WL way to do it

```
"ABCA" // Characters // Permutations // Map[StringJoin]

{"ABCA", "ABAC", "ACBA", "ACAB", "AABC", "AACB", "BACA", "BAAC", "BCAA", "CABA", "CAAB", "CBAA"}
```

Comment: As I am new to Mathematica I did not know that there was already a function for all permutations! Thank you for letting me know - in that case I do not have to convert my code anymore...

Comment: @studentnr You are welcome. If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it and upvoting.